# Already higher than takeoff altitude(not descending)

Tags: python, quadcopter, uav, mavlink

I have the following Python code that arms and take off the UAV using `pymavlink`. I am using the px4 flight stake

```py
from pymavlink import mavutil
drone_connection = mavutil.mavlink_connection('udpin:127.0.0.1:14550')
drone_connection.wait_heartbeat()

drone_connection.mav.command_long_send(drone_connection.target_system, drone_connection.target_system, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_COMPONENT_ARM_DISARM,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)

arm_msg = drone_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK',blocking=True)
print(arm_msg)


drone_connection.mav.command_long_send(drone_connection.target_system, drone_connection.target_component, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10)
take_off_msg= drone_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK',blocking=True)
print(take_off_msg)
print("Executuion end")
```

Terminal output

```
COMMAND_ACK {command : 400, result : 0, progress : 0, result_param2 : 0, target_system : 255, target_component : 0}
COMMAND_ACK {command : 22, result : 0, progress : 0, result_param2 : 0, target_system : 255, target_component : 0}
Executuion end
```

The UAV arms. However, for takeoff, it gives the following error in Qgroundcontrol:

```
Already higher than takeoff altitude(not descending)
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question ... please edit a clear, focused question into your post

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [takeoff.cpp](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/blob/main/src/modules/navigator/takeoff.cpp), that error is generated at line 114-120. Looking at [line 114](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/blob/main/src/modules/navigator/takeoff.cpp#L114C2-L114C69), in particular

```py
if (takeoff_altitude_amsl < _navigator->get_global_position()->alt)
```

From [`MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF`](https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-mavlink-mission-command-messages-mav_cmd.html#mav-cmd-nav-takeoff) (emphasis is mine):

> The vehicle will climb straight up from its current location to the specified altitude. If the mission is begun while the copter is already flying, the vehicle will climb straight up to the specified altitude, ***if the vehicle is already above the altitude the command will be ignored and the mission will move on to the next command immediately***.

So, the UAV *thinks* that it is higher than 10 m - it ignores the take off command, issues the error (which is more like a *warning*) and moves to the next command, which is

```py
print("Executuion end")
```

So, this is totally as expected.

As a sanity check, and this may be a total stab in the dark, but are you *already* at a high elevation (i.e. a tall building, on a hill/mountain, or in a city at high altitude)?

Try increasing the altitude (in steps of 10), and see if that helps. So, change the last parameter in:

```py
drone_connection.mav.command_long_send(drone_connection.target_system, drone_connection.target_component, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10)
```

to `20`

```py
drone_connection.mav.command_long_send(drone_connection.target_system, drone_connection.target_component, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20)
```

then `30`, `40`, etc.

Either that, or your altimeter may have an issue, or be incorrectly calibrated.